# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installer does not recognize Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, system-installation

I have been struggling with this for about 10 days with no luck. So after numerous installs of both OSs I now feel I need some help. I know there are many versions of this question posted already but none has worked for me so far.

My system has 3 HDDs (2*TGB, 1*250GB)and 1SSD and I want to install windows on the SSD and Ubuntu on the 250GB HDD. I also want the windows 7 swap file on a partition on the 1st 1TB HDD (correct me if I'm wrong but I think having the swap file on the SSD is not a good idea) and 3 partitions on the 250GB HDD: Root, Home and Swap. The second 1TB HDD is contains loads of files I really must not lose.

Currently, I have installed windows 7 on SSD but when I try to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside it, windows is not recognized so I don't get that option. In the past couple of days I did have both working but I couldn't get grub to see windows and had to switch using UEFI.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA WDC WD10EZRX-00A (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  16.8GB  16.8GB  ntfs
 2      16.8GB  1000GB  983GB   ntfs


Model: ATA WDC WD10EZRX-00A (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ntfs


Model: ATA WDC WD2500AAJS-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags


Model: ATA Samsung SSD 840 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB  105MB  fat32        EFI system partition          boot
 2      106MB   240MB  134MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      240MB   500GB  500GB  ntfs         Basic data partition


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!                           

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

EDIT- 
Using GParted, I can see the screen bellow:

[GParted](https://files.one.ubuntu.com/PmZVijXRTliXC93NfLFwBQ)

I am not sure what the unknown file system on sdd2 is.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Use `parted` (not fdisk which is for MBR, not UEFI) in Linux. Also, I'd put the swap for Linux and Windows on the SSD.

Comment: Hmmm. Am I right to think that the issue I've been having is caused by the sdb partition being msdos?

Comment: No. That's telling you that drive is MBR. Also, "sdb" is not a partition - it's a drive. "sdb1" is a partition, and it's NTFS (in your post).

Comment: Thanks for the correction Elliott. I'm quite new to this so I wasn't sure how to express what I meant properly. I do understand the difference between drive and partition though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might just have to save your data to a backup disc and reformat the drive windows was on. The Ubuntu installer cant read some windows and mac filesystems.

Comment: Thanks Nick but I have tried this with no luck. in fact this was my first thought. Maybe it is the way I format /dev/sdd through the windows installer. Is it worth formatting it again using GParted?